# Using Typescript object spread operator with this keyword

Tags: typescript2.0

In my code I often have to copy data from json to instantiate class in constructor.

```
function append(dst, src) {
    for (let key in src) {
        if (src.hasOwnProperty(key) {
            dst[key] = src[key];
        }
    }
};


export class DataClass {
    id: number;
    title: string;
    content: string;
    img: null | string;
    author: string; 
    // no methods, just raw data from API
}


export class AdoptedClass1 extends DataClass {
    // has same fields as DataClass
    showcase: string;

    constructor (data: DataClass) {
        append(data, this);

        // do some stuff
    }
}


// similar code for AdoptedClass2
```

I'm wondering if I can replace append function call in constructor with object spread operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your need I'll prefer to use `Object.assign(this, data)` over your custom made `append` function. Nevertheless have a look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to understand the limitation of it.

Back to your main question: it is not possible to use the spread operator to do what you want. Many people are interested in that feature but it has been put on hold as you can see [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3895).

To get closer of what you ask we can refactor your code a little:

```
export class DataClass {
    id: number
    title: string
    content: string
    img: null | string
    author: string
    constructor(data: DataClass) {
        Object.assign(this, data)
    }
}

export class AdoptedClass1 extends DataClass {
    showcase: string

    constructor (data: DataClass) {
        super(data)

        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

By simply adding the `constructor` to the data class you will be allowed to use `super(data)` in children and IMHO the code will be a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object spread operator by replacing this line:

```
append(data,this)
```

with this line

```
data = {...data, ...this};
```

Comment: this would set the incoming argument, not the instance of the class itself